# Axios doesn't return response body if I don't set parameters explicitly in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I use api to get football statistics using axios which take an object as a paramater. The object contains some information like endpoint url and headers. If I pass values to url parameters, it will not return data body. But If I set it explicitly it will do. I to convert values to string but it didn't work too.  (Look at getStandings function below)

Update: `props.league` and `props.season` are not `null`, they get their values from clicked buttons in `App.js`.

**Standings.js**

```
import React,{ ReactDOM } from 'react'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import getStandings from '../api/getStandings'

function Standings(props) {
  const [standings, setStandings] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getStandings(props.league, props.season)
      .then((response) => {
        setStandings(response.data.response[0].league.standings[0])                                          
      })       
  }, [props])
   
  return (
    <div>
      <table className='table table-hover'>
        // some html code
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Standings
```

**getStandings.js**

```
 import axios from 'axios'

 async function getStandings(league, season) {
   let config = {
     method: 'GET',
     url: `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=${league}&season=${season}`,
     // If I write `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=39&season=2022` it will return response body
     headers: {
       'x-rapidapi-host': 'v3.football.api-sports.io',
       'x-rapidapi-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
     }
   };
      
   return axios(config)
 }
    
 export default getStandings
```

Comment: Check if  `props.league` and `props.season` is undefined in `Standings.js`

Comment: no, they are defined, they get their values from clicked button which send the props

Comment: It might be helpful for debugging to start the `getStandings` function with ```const url = `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=${league}&season=${season}`; console.log({ url }); let config = { ...``` and then use the `url` value in the axios request so that you can see the result of the string interpolation you are sending in the request just to make sure it is being received by the function and interpolated properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your api function. If I were you, I would try print props and see what's in there first.

ex)

```
import React,{ ReactDOM } from 'react'
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import getStandings from '../api/getStandings'


function Standings(props){
console.log('props', props)       <--- print props
const [standings,setStandings]=useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
       
            getStandings(props.league,props.season).then((response)=>{
                setStandings( response.data.response[0].league.standings[0] )                                          
            })       
            
        
        
    },[props])

   
    return(
        <div>
            <table className='table table-hover'>
                // some html code
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Standings
```

Comment: Does the problem relate to async/await technique ?

Answer (score 0):

use the optional operator to prevent the `undefined` issues, also don't use the `props` object as a dependency in the `useEffect` hook instead use `props.league` and `props.season` due to the `useEffect` shallow comparison. so here is my solution it might seem helpful:

```
import React,{ ReactDOM } from 'react'
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import getStandings from '../api/getStandings'

function Standings(props){
const [standings,setStandings]=useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
            getStandings(props.league,props.season).then((response)=>{
                setStandings( response.data?.response[0]?.league?.standings[0] )                                          
            })       
    },[props.league, props.season])

   
    return(
        <div>
            <table className='table table-hover'>
                // some html code
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Standings;
```